# No data in UITableView from xib

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xib, nib

I'm trying to create a custom keyboard, showing a list of choices.

I've created a xib-file (based on `UIView`) which only contains a `UITableView`.

I've created `ListKeyBoardView`.h and `ListKeyBoardView.m` (see code below). In `ListKeyBoardView.m` I load the nib-file and the `UITableView` from the xib is hooked up to the UITableView ithrough Interface Builder. After loading the nib-file I've checked the frame size of the `UITableView`. It is the same size as the `UITableView` in Interface Builder, so it seems to be hooked up correctly. However when I run the app and the view is shown, it is completely blank.

I've set the delegate and datasource for the `UITableView` in the code and the method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is called (returning 6), but `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not called.

To check for other errors I created the `UITableView` manually in the code (see commented line) and then it is working fine. What I am missing?

```
#import "ListKeyBoardView.h"

@interface ListKeyBoardView () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *listTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *listData;

@end


@implementation ListKeyBoardView

- (id)init {
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 250)];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
         [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ListKeyboard" owner:self options:nil];
//        self.listTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];

        NSLog(@"Frame = %f, %f", self.listTableView.frame.size.width, self.listTableView.frame.size.height);
        [self addSubview:self.listTableView];

        self.listTableView.delegate = self;
        self.listTableView.dataSource = self;

        [self.listTableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ListItem"];

        self.listData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self.listData addObject:@"een"];
        [self.listData addObject:@"twee"];
        [self.listData addObject:@"drie"];
        [self.listData addObject:@"vier"];
        [self.listData addObject:@"vijf"];
        [self.listData addObject:@"zes"];
    }
    return self;
}


#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [self.listData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ListItem";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.listData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to implement `-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`

Do it like this:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: numberOfSectionsInTableView: is optional. To be sure I implemented it anyway and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the tableView is created in storyboard and thus initWithCoder is called and not initWithFrame.

To solve, override initWithCoder rather than initWithFrame and do not override the init method to call initWithFrame.